# Django TypeError: Expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, django

I am writing a webpage that can run a python script by clicking a button on html. Here is what I have:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
from subprocess import run,PIPE


def external(request):
    inp= request.POST.get('param')
    out= run([sys.executable,'test.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    print(out)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data1':out.stdout})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

# urlconf
urlpatterns = [
    path('external/', views.external)
]
```

home.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Python button script
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/external/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        Input Text:
        <input type="text" name="param" required><br><br>
        {{data_external}}<br><br>
        {{data1}}
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute External Python Script">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

[directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIjNe.png)

The problem is with this line of code: `out= run([sys.executable,'test.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)` from views.py. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: print `inp` and check if you are getting something in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using this view(external) for both the `POST` method and the `GET` method, and you do not have data in the get method, so you get an error.

try this:

```
def external(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        inp= request.POST.get('param')
        out= run([sys.executable,'test.py',inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
        print(out)
        return render(request,'home.html',{'data1':out.stdout})
    else:
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

Comment: it works!! thank you so much